# How to write a query that joins 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, relational-division

I am having issues with this query that utilizes three different tables. I also believe I will be using the key words NOT EXISTS and NOT WITHIN but I am not completely positive on this. I will post the query definition, the tables I am using, and what I have tried so far. Thanks for the help in advance!

Query:

```
Find the users that create jobs that utilize all proteins.
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Protein(pid INTEGER,name varchar(50),PRIMARY KEY(pid));

CREATE TABLE Job(uid INTEGER,job_id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,input 
varchar(500),status varchar(100),start_time time,finish_time time,FOREIGN 
KEY(uid) REFERENCES User(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE,PRIMARY KEY(job_id));

CREATE TABLE User(uid INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,address VARCHAR(40),city 
VARCHAR(20),state VARCHAR(20),zipcode VARCHAR(10), username 
VARCHAR(10),email VARCHAR(30),primary key (uid));

CREATE TABLE job_protein(job_id INTEGER, pid INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(job_id, pid));
```

What Ive tried so far...

```
SELECT u.uid, j.jobid, count(j.jobid)
FROM job j
INNER JOIN job_proteins p
ON j.jobid = p.jobid
INNER JOIN user u
ON p.uid = u.uid
GROUP BY j.jobid
HAVING count(j.jobid) = (SELECT count(pid) FROM Protein);
```

Does what I have get jobs that utilize every protein?.

Comment: "ON p.uid = u.uid" => "ON j.uid = u.uid" ad job_protein does not have uid.

Comment: in the sql version I'm using I think that  that query would fail because u.uid is not contained in the group by clause or in an aggregate function

Answer (score 1):

Missing a member in your group by clause:

```
SELECT u.uid, j.jobid, count(j.jobid)
FROM job j
INNER JOIN job_proteins p
ON j.jobid = p.jobid
INNER JOIN user u
ON p.uid = j.uid -- and you had wrong alias here
GROUP BY u.uid, j.jobid -- right here
HAVING count(j.jobid) = (SELECT count(pid) FROM Protein);
```

Comment: Although I would probably do the Proteins count into a variable and then use that in the having clause

Comment: So this gets me a list of all the job ids that use every protein?

Comment: I believe so yes... you had the basic idea correct, just a couple of syntactical issues.

Comment: Note that the count(j.jobid) will be redundant... it will always equal the number of rows in the proteins table.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your query, because you do not seem to need the `user` table.

Second, your problem statement is ambiguous.  If the goal is to find users that have *one* job should have all the proteins, then the following gets the user/job pairs:

```
SELECT j.uid, jp.jobid, count(*)
FROM job j JOIN
     job_proteins jp
     ON j.jobid = jp.jobid
GROUP BY j.uid, jp.jobid
HAVING count(distinct jp.pid) = (SELECT count(*) FROM Protein);
```

A slight modification gets the just the users:

```
SELECT DISTINCT j.uid
FROM job j JOIN
     job_proteins jp
     ON j.jobid = jp.jobid
GROUP BY j.uid, jp.jobid
HAVING count(distinct jp.pid) = (SELECT count(*) FROM Protein);
```

NOTE:  This is one of the very few cases where `SELECT DISTINCT` is used with `GROUP BY`.

If the goal is to find users that use *all* the proteins across their jobs:

```
SELECT j.uid
FROM job j JOIN
     job_proteins jp
     ON j.jobid = jp.jobid
GROUP BY j.uid
HAVING count(distinct jp.pid) = (SELECT count(*) FROM Protein);
```

The difference from the first query is that the `GROUP BY` clause changed.